# Is it possible to run a .app stored with another apps bundle?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

Is it feasible to have a .app within an XCode project and then launch that when certain conditions are met?

As a more general overview, I'm looking to create a 'wrapper' for an existing app.
As a basic example, imagine you were given an app, with no code/project access (just the compiled app), and wanted to add a splash screen (that isn't the use but for this it doesn't make a difference), how would you achieve this (if it's possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple once I'd thought about it. Include your .app in the bundle.
The following will launch a .app within your apps bundle:

```
NSString *appPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"appName" ofType:@"app"];
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:appPath];
```